# Mongo Go Driver is getting interface conversion error when SetSort used

Tags: mongodb, go

I would like to change order my documents in Mongo DB using Go. I have valid json string code and i can marshal it successfully in to `map[string]int`. The sample of this type just like:
`[{year 1}, {lastupdated -1}]`. The value presents order `year` field ascending and `lastupdated` field descending. This struct is aspect of MongoDB understands. Also I'm pass this data into `bson.D` type. Here is my code:

```golang
if queries["order"] != nil {
        var unmarshalledOrder map[string]int
        json.Unmarshal(queries["order"].([]byte), &unmarshalledOrder)

        docRes := make(bson.D, 0)
        for field, sort := range unmarshalledOrder {
            docRes = append(docRes, bson.DocElem{field, sort})
        }

        log.Println(docRes)
    }
```

When I print `docRes`, everthing goes well. But i pass the data to `options.Sort` function, the function throws `interface conversion: interface {} is runtime.errorString, not string` panic. Is it a bug on mongo go driver or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code you've written which uses the driver? Based on the use of `bson.DocElem`, I think you're using mgo, but mgo's `Query.Sort` method takes strings, not documents (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/globalsign/mgo?tab=doc#Query.Sort).

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I resolved the problem a few hours ago (i used Aggregation framework api). Also I don't use mgo. Thanks